# ACF - get checkbox values inside flexible content field

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, advanced-custom-fields

Have been going around and around with this and can't make it work - probably something very simple but I've got no hair left - can anyone help me?

```
<?php
if( have_rows('page_content') ):
while ( have_rows('page_content') ) : the_row();

    if( get_row_layout() == 'specs' ):

        // check if the nested repeater field has rows of data
        if( get_sub_field('objectives') ):
        echo '<ul>';
        $field = get_field_object('objectives');
        $value = $field['value'];
        $choices = $field['choices'];

            // loop through the rows of data
            foreach( $value as $v):
                echo '<li>'.$choices.'</li>';

            endforeach;
            echo '</ul>';
        endif;
    endif;
endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working now ... thanks to the great support team at ACF. I was missing the [$v] after .$choices. Working code below:

```
<?php
if( have_rows('page_content') ):
while ( have_rows('page_content') ) : the_row();

if( get_row_layout() == 'specs' ):

    // check if the nested repeater field has rows of data
    if( get_sub_field('objectives') ):
    echo '<ul>';
    $field = get_field_object('objectives');
    $value = $field['value'];
    $choices = $field['choices'];

        // loop through the rows of data
        foreach( $value as $v):
            echo '<li>'.$choices.'</li>';

        endforeach;
        echo '</ul>';
    endif;
endif;
endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the Key of ACF field like this,

```
$field_key = "field_5039a99716d1d";
$field = get_field_object($field_key);
```

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field_object/

Comment: Thanks Khushi but didn't work - I updated code to include field key but no change.

Comment: Can you please tell me what you are getting in $field array?

Comment: see this link may be it will help you [Learn more](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/repeater-field-and-checkbox/)

Comment: It did help @Khushi! But not 100%. Realised that I needed to use **get_sub_field_object** rather than **get_field_object**. 

I'm now getting 'Array' for all items whether I echo $choices or $value. 

$field is returning 23 items in the array, e.g. (label, type, name, key, etc.)
$value is returning selected 6 items, e.g. **[0]=>  string(9) "CheckItemName"**
$choices is returning all items e.g. **["CheckItemName"]=> string(9) "CheckItemName**